# Soft wdt Reset - ESP8266/NodeMCU

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

When I upload my code , after 3 iterations of the loop() , I get an soft wdt reset and the NodeMCU restarts. It happens everytime. What would be the error ?

```
#include <dummy.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

// Set these to run example.
#define FIREBASE_HOST "plugmatebeta.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "zQtW9gVXzNuz1tD8OzaTCoFpIx7MbFjwyncsWnGC"                       
#define WIFI_SSID "6LowPAN"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "rashmin0703"
#define WifiAlertLED D3
#define pushButton D6
#define outsideButton D7
#define relay D8
#define connectedLED D2

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting: ");
  delay(5000);

//  while (WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
//    Serial.print(".");
//    delay(100);
//  }
//  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
//  delay(1000);

  pinMode(WifiAlertLED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(connectedLED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pushButton,INPUT);
  pinMode(outsideButton,INPUT);
  pinMode(relay,OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
        digitalWrite(connectedLED, LOW);
        WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
        Serial.print("connecting");
        BlinkLED();
        controlOne();
        delay(1000);
    }
  else{
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("inside connected");
    controlTwo();
  }
}


void BlinkLED(){
  digitalWrite(WifiAlertLED, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(100);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(WifiAlertLED, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(100);   
}

void controlOne(){
  if ((digitalRead(pushButton) == HIGH) && (digitalRead(outsideButton)==HIGH) ){
         digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
         Serial.println("on");
  }else{
         digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
         Serial.println("off");
  }
}

void controlTwo(){
  String firebaseResult = firebaseAction();
  if ((digitalRead(pushButton) == HIGH) && ( (firebaseResult=="1") || (digitalRead(outsideButton)==HIGH) ) ){
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    Serial.println("onnnnnnnnn");
    publishtoFirebase("ON");
  }else{
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    Serial.println("onnnnnnnnn");
    publishtoFirebase("OFF");
  } 
}


String firebaseAction(){
    String x =Firebase.getString("/plgm8-1/command");
    yield();
    delay(200);
    Serial.println(x);
    return x;
    delay(100);
}

void publishtoFirebase(String x){
  Firebase.setString("/plgm8-1/status", x);
  delay(200);
  yield();
}
```

I tried searching for errors regarding , soft wdt reset more , but it seems like the resources are very low. Is it a problem with the timer of the NodeMCU ?

Comment: I don't have the hardware setting as yours, so can't verify what exactly going wrong. But you should keep things related to setting, configuration and initialisation in `setup()`, and only include the execution in the `loop()`. For example, WiFi only need to setup once, not every loop. BTW, what is the `while..loop` that is comment-out in the `setup()`? it shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call WiFi.begin OR Firebase.begin more than once.
Once the ESP connects in setup, it will re-connect on it's own if the connection drops, you don't need to handle this inside your loop.

I think you should un-comment the code you have in your setup function and then in loop, just call your `controlTwo();`

There is one thing to watch out for.  There is a watchdog timer that will fire if you spend too much time doing nothing, particularly in the setup function, so try to avoid too many un-needed calls to delay or an infinite loop in setup.

Here is a hacked up version of your code that I think should work.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting: ");
  delay(5000);

   while (WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    BlinkLED();
    controlOne();
    delay(100);
   }
   Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
   delay(1000);

  pinMode(WifiAlertLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(connectedLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(outsideButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("inside connected");
  controlTwo();
  delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It resets because you're doing something wrong with the way you're handling the Wi-Fi connection. It happened to me once when I tried to make a http request before connecting to the server. The compiler does not see this, so you need to know what you're doing.

Try to run the `WiFi.begin()` function only once in `setup()` and close the connection to the firebase server when you're done with it, or just run it once if you want it connected to server 24/7.